# React navigation not navigating to correct screen

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I have created 3 stack navigators, `HomeStack`, `PermissionsStack`, and `AppStack`. I have them in a `drawerNavigator` like so:

```
export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeStack, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => null} },
    Permissions: { screen: PermissionsStack, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => null} },
    Explore: { screen: AppStack, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => 'Explore'} },
    ContactScreen: { screen: AppStack, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => 'Contact & Support'} },
    TOU: { screen: AppStack, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => 'Terms of Use'} },
    Privacy: { screen: AppStack, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => 'Privacy Policy'} },
    Disclaimer: { screen: AppStack },
    Settings: { screen: AppStack, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => null} },
});
```

From the `Home` screen, there is a link to `TOU`, but it doesn't go to `TOU` and it instead goes to `Explore`. The `onPress` for the button on `Home` is `this.props.navigation.navigate('TOU')`. Is this not correct?

You can run this project yourself and view the issue here: https://gitlab.com/jefffabiny/navigation-issue

Answer (score 0):

You register the same `StackNavigators` multiple times.
And the initial route of the `AppStack` is `Explore`.

I have never used the `DrawerNavigator` but you should nest navigators like this:

```
export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },
    Permissions: { screen: PermissionsStack },
    App: { screen: AppStack },
});
```

I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve but if you want to access `TOU` from the drawer and not only inside the `Stack` you could do it like this:

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
    ...
    TOU: {
        screen: TOU,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: 'Terms of Use',
        })
    },
    ...
});

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },
    Permissions: { screen: PermissionsStack },
    App: { screen: AppStack },
    TOU: { screen: TOU }
});
```